# How to save images in camera roll in iphone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, camera-roll

I am developing one application. In that I want to save my pictures in camera roll. So how to save my pictures in camera roll through code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most basic way (and the only way if you're targeting iOS before 4.0) is to use [`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum). This lets you specify a selector to be called on a target object when the save is complete.

In 4.0, you can use ALAssetsLibrary's [`writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:) to write the image; in this case, you provide a block to be called when the save is complete.

In 4.1, you can also use ALAssetsLibrary's [`writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:) or [`writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:) to write an image along with metadata (e.g. geotagging information). The former is also the only way to write an image from an NSData object without first loading it as a UIImage or CGImageRef.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/camera/save-an-image-to-camera-roll.html) blog post..UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum is your friend..